# Mean value theorem for surface integrals: Shrinking surface of integration to $0$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus

Consider a disk of radius $R$, area $A$, somewhere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider a vector function $\vec{F}: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. I form the surface integral over the disk

$$ \iint_{\text{disk}} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} \\
\iint_{\text{disk}} F_ndS
$$

where $F_n$ indicates the normal component to the oriented surface. I applied the Mean Value Theorem for integrals (which I'm assuming works for any integral of any dimension) to get

$$ F_n(P^*)A$$

where $P^*$ is some point on the disk. I form the equation

$$ \frac{1}{A}\iint F_ndS = F_n(P^*)$$
Now I take the limit

$$ \lim_{A\to 0}\frac{1}{A}\iint F_ndS = \lim_{A\to0}F_n(P^*) $$

What value will $F_n(P^*)$ converge to? Will it converge to the value over the center of the disk $F_n(P_0)$? I've done limits along paths in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, I've never done limits of surface areas embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is such an operation well defined? If the disk shrinks uniformly, I can imagine $F_n(P^*) \to F_n(P_0)$ where $P_0$ is the center of the disk. However, if one side shrinks faster than the other, I can imagine $F_n(P^*)$ converging to any value we like depending on how we shrink the area. I could ask the same question for $1$-dimensional domains. Taking the limit after applying the Mean Value Theorem

$$ \lim_{h\to0} \frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h} f(x) dx = \lim_{h\to0} f(c) = f(a)$$

However, if I ask

$$ \lim_{\ell \to 0} \frac{1}{\ell} \int_{a}^b f(x) dx$$

where $\ell = b- a$ is the interval length, is such an operation well defined?

Comment: The mean value theorem is in fact quite specific to one dimensional settings. In general, with several variables we get [an inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I remember seeing a mean value theorem for double integrals in my textbook. Are you talking about the mean value theorem for derivatives?

Comment: We still don't get what you want with vector valued functions. The article linked has an example; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_integration_fails_for_vector-valued_functions).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Ah that's interesting. Are there a class of functions which do satisfy the theorem? Because a surface integral is not much different than a double integral. It's still a volume over the surface where the height is given by $F_n$. It seems like it should work for some functions, but maybe not

Comment: Going from a single variable to multiple variables is a big change. I guess the most common but still powerful example is that things like saddles don't exist in one dimension.

Comment: Related to the shrinking domain question- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. More motivation to learn real analysis!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mean value theorem for multiple integrals. For example, if $f:U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $U$ is compact and rectifiable, then there is a point $\xi \in U$, **not necessarily unique**, such that

$$\int_U f = f(\xi)\cdot \text{area}(U)$$

This is proved in the usual way, noting that if $f$ attains minimum (maximum) values $m (M)$, then $m \cdot \text{area}(U) \leqslant \int_Uf \leqslant M \cdot \text{area}(U).$

It seems you have in mind an integral over a "nice" surface that can be parameterized as $S = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3| \,\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{g}(s,t), \,(s,t)\in U \subset \mathbb{R}^2\}$, where $\mathbf{g} \in C^1(U)$ and $U$ is compact and rectifiable.

The surface integral can be expressed as
$$\int_S F_n \, dS= \int\int_U F_n(\mathbf{g}(s,t)) \left\|\frac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial t} \right\|\, ds\,dt,$$

and if $F_n$ is continuous, the entire integrand is continuous. Whence, there is a point $(\xi,\eta) \in U$ such that

$$\int_S F_n \, dS = F_n(\mathbf{g}(\xi,\eta)) \left\|\frac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial t} \right\|_{(\xi,\eta)}\cdot\text{area}(U)$$

Is "shrinking" the surface is a well-defined operation? The answer is only if you specify the operation as such. For example, construct a decreasing sequence of subsets $S_k$ where $S_{k+1} \subset S_k \subset S$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_k = \{\mathbf{q} \}$.  There will be a corresponding sequence of subsets $U_k \subset U$ and a point $(s_q,t_q) = \mathbf{g}^{-1}(\mathbf{q})$.

Applying the mean value theorem we find a sequence $(\xi_k,\eta_k)$ converging to $(s_q,t_q)$ such that

$$\frac{1}{\text{area}(S_k)} \int_{S_k} F_n \, dS = F_n(\mathbf{g}(\xi_k,\eta_k)) \left\|\frac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial t} \right\|_{(\xi_k,\eta_k)} \cdot \frac{\text{area}(U_k)}{\text{area}(S_k)},$$

which should converge as $k \to \infty$ to $F_n(\mathbf{q})$.

To reiterate, the particular value of the limit will depend on how the shrinking process is specified, as illustrated by taking your example further:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h} f(x) \, dx = f(a), \\ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{b-h}^{b} f(x) \, dx = f(b)$$

Comment: Thank you for this really nice answer! Motivation for this question: consider a surface $S$ with oriented normal vectors. The surface has a charge density $\sigma(S)$. As you go from one side of the surface to the over, the electric field undergoes a discontinuity in its normal component to the surface of size $\sigma/\epsilon_0$. Every source on the internet, and many textbooks never give a proof of this very very important result! They use Gauss's law $\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{S} = \int \sigma dS$. Everyone says "let your Gaussian surface be a cylinder through a patch of charge"

Comment: They say 'let the patch be small so that $\sigma$ is approximately constant.' Then they say let the length of the cylinder go to zero so you get no flux through the sides of the cylinder. Then because the patch is small (top's and bottom cylinder lids are small), this some how makes the E field constant and blah blah. They have 2 limits going on. The cylinder length and size of lids A. Somehow letting $A$ go to zero makes the normal vectors of the gaussian surface, equal to the normal vector of the surface of interest with the charge. And many other assumptions.Thanks again

Comment: @DWade64: You're welcome.

Comment: I'm using a multivariable calculus textbook designed for a first pass through (author Jon Rogawski). If I may pose this question here (as opposed to starting a new question). Consider a map $G: D\subset R^2 \to R^2$. He writes Area(G(D)) $\approx |J_G$|(P) Area(D), where D is small, $J_G$ is the jacobian matrix, and P is a sample point in D. He writes, the more precise relationship is |$J_G$|(P) = $\lim_{|D|\to0}$ Area(G(D))/Area(D), where $|D|\to 0$ indicates the limit as the diameter of D (maximum distance b/w 2 points in D) tends to 0. What point P does he have in mind? Is it well-defined?

Comment: Or rather, he does define a particular shrinking procedure, and point $P$ is whatever it is. Who knows what it will be. I guess it's a question of "do I specifying the shrinking procedure first and let the point be what it is, or do I specify the point first and find a shrinking procedure to get there"

Comment: That's a pretty vague argument, particularly since it uses the $\approx$ notion which is not precise.  It would be better to use Area(G(D)) = $\int_D 1 \cdot |J_G|$ and apply the mean value theorem. In the end it reduces to $|J_G|(P)$ so its clear he has a specific point $P$ in mind and the shrinking procedure is defined through a sequence of sets $D_n$ or a continuous transformation $t \mapsto D_t$ where $P$ is always an element of those sets.

Answer (score 1):

If the vector field ${\bf v}$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $P_0$ then for any disc $D$ with center $P_0$ and unit normal ${\bf  n}$ one has
$$\int_D{\bf v}\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega= {\bf v}(P_*)\cdot{\bf n}\ {\rm area}(D)$$
for some $P_*\in D$. This follows from the standard MVT for continuous real-valued functions on a path-connected set $D\subset{\mathbb R}^3$. It follows that
$$\lim_{r(D)\to 0+}{1\over{\rm area}(D)}\int_D{\bf v}\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega= {\bf v}(P_0)\cdot{\bf n}\ .$$
But you can also set up an $\epsilon/\delta$-proof that does not make use of the MVT.